# Batch to process files one by one

Tags: windows, batch-file, multiple-instances

I have a batch file to compress PNG files. When I drag and drop some files on batch, it starts to process all of them in the same time. And it becomes useless when I tried with hundreds of files (sure)

The main part is something like that *(simplified)*

```
START "" /W truepng.exe /out "%~n1_out1.png" %1
START "" /W pngwolf.exe --in="%~n1_out1.png" --out="%~n1_out2.png"
```

I think I must to solve the "%1" part.
I'm trying to make batch to process files with 4-file blocks. Thinking of 2 different aproach, and both fine.

**1.** Will process the first 4 file, after continue with other 4

**2.** Or it will run maximum 4 "pngwolf.exe" instances in the same time (best option)

In my several tests, I started to try with a counter logic %1 %2 %3 %4 after %n...
But even in that phase I stucked and couldn't create a counter system.
No need to ask, sure I'm newbie on batch coding. But even to be a good designer, looks like I need to learn more on batch.
Thanks for anyone will give a hand. Hope there is a simple solution that I can understand and adaptate.

All Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a instances=4
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
::
:loop
SET "nextfile=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED nextfile (
 ECHO all done
 DEL "%tempfile%a*" >NUL 2>NUL
 GOTO :eof
)

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%instances%) DO (
 IF NOT EXIST "%tempfile%a%%a" (
  >"%tempfile%a%%a" ECHO.
  START "Instance %%a" oneconversion "%~1" "%tempfile%a%%a" %%a
  SHIFT
  GOTO loop
 )
)
timeout /t 1 >NUL
GOTO loop

GOTO :EOF
```

Where **oneconversion.bat** is

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
START "" /W truepng.exe /out "%~n1_out1.png" %1
START "" /W pngwolf.exe --in="%~n1_out1.png" --out="%~n1_out2.png"
DEL "%~2" >NUL 2>NUL
cls
exit
```

As a dummy to prove the principle, I used as **oneconversion.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
TITLE Processing %~1
SET /a wait=%~3*6
timeout /t %wait%
DEL "%~2" >NUL 2>NUL
CLS
exit
```

which is why the third parameter is supplied - it's only there to make `oneconversion.bat` variable-length.

The operation is fairly simple: establish a dummy temporary file and assume that that filename + a number is available as a flag file.

for each available instance (set to 4 - could be virtually anything) check for the flagfile, if it's missing, create it and despatch the next conversion, passing the required filename and temfilename. When the conversion's done, kill off the tempfile.

---

Edit to be more communicative:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a instances=4
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
::
:loop
SET "nextfile=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED nextfile (
 IF EXIST "%tempfile%a" DEL "%tempfile%a"&ECHO All jobs started&GOTO loop
 IF EXIST "%tempfile%a*" GOTO delay
 ECHO all done
 pause
 GOTO :eof
)

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%instances%) DO (
 IF NOT EXIST "%tempfile%a%%a" (
  >"%tempfile%a%%a" ECHO.
  START "Instance %%a" oneconversion "%~1" "%tempfile%a%%a" %%a
  SHIFT
  GOTO loop
 )
)
:delay
timeout /t 1 >NUL
GOTO loop

GOTO :EOF
```

Very small changes:

When `nextfile` is found to be `not defined`, then all parameters have been exhausted. Look for the tempfile "%tempfile%a" - this has no affxed instance number and was being arbirarily deleted. If it exists, delete it and show the message "all jobs started" - there will still be jobs running, but no more will be addded, and go back to the loop.

Next time no parameters are found, "%tempfile%a" will not exist, so see whether any `"%tempfile%a*"` exists - which will indicate the subsidiary batch isn't finished. If such a file exists, go to `delay` to wait a second and try again.

When all of the jobs have finished, echo `all done` and pause to allow the message to be read.

Naturally, if you insert a control-g character into a displayed message, there will be a beep sounded if you want an audio alert.

Comment: Principle proved !  Working great in first try. I'm over edits with the real code (not simplified) and backup mechanisms etc. This is a PNG compress approach that I made maybe 2000 tests to balance performance and efficiency. I will share after adaptate. Batch file was the last piece. Thank you.

Comment: Hi; I would like to ask one more question if possible. Script works "perpect" I just would like to add an END message and sound. I tried to find an end point in main script but I couldn't. I somehow confused me. Where can I place a command to execute in end?

Comment: I'm trying to make a modification on code but couldn't succeed. Hope you'll be able to see the post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375747/multithreaded-batch-file-passing-parameters

Answer (score 1):

The variable that contains all parameters passed into the script is `%*`

You can process one at a time by using a for loop:

```
for %%A in (%*) do (
    START "" /W truepng.exe /out "%%~nA_out1.png" %%%A
    START "" /W pngwolf.exe --in="%%~nA_out1.png" --out="%%~nA_out2.png"
)
```

---

To process batches of four simultaneously, run all four instances of truepng first, and then all four instances of pngwolf.

```
:: Process four sets of truepng at once
start "" truepng.exe /out "%~n1_out1.png" %1
start "" truepng.exe /out "%~n2_out1.png" %2
start "" truepng.exe /out "%~n3_out1.png" %3
start "" truepng.exe /out "%~n4_out1.png" %4

:: Wait for 1 second/let the above commands catch up
ping -n 1 1.1.1.1>nul

:: Process four sets of pngwolf at once
start "" pngwolf.exe --in="%~1_out1.png" --out="%~n1_out2.png"
start "" pngwolf.exe --in="%~2_out1.png" --out="%~n2_out2.png"
start "" pngwolf.exe --in="%~3_out1.png" --out="%~n3_out2.png"
start "" pngwolf.exe --in="%~4_out1.png" --out="%~n4_out2.png"
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try. But is there a way to modify it to process files with 4 instances? One by one will be extremely slow.

Comment: If you remove the `/W` flag, you can call truepng and pngwolf with %1, %2, %3, and %4 and they will run simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry can't since pngwolf is using truepng's output. And when I remove from pngwolf, "nearly" nothing changed as expected. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @inovasyon - I've added code to process multiple inputs simultaneously.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In question I mentioned in case of "hundreds of files". That's why I need a batch script. Not just 4. And another issue is truepng's process time varies seconds to several minutes. I can not define a fixed delay. But thanks again to try help.