# Multithreaded batch file passing parameters

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file

The multithreading part was already [replied here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521879/batch-to-process-files-one-by-one/28522570#28522570) and works great  (thanks a lot to [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo))

**Main code**

```
SET /a instances=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%?" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
::
:loop
SET "nextfile=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED nextfile (
DEL "%tempfile%a*" >NUL 2>NUL
::ECHO all done
exit
)

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%instances%) DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%tempfile%a%%a" (
>"%tempfile%a%%a" ECHO.
START /B "Instance %%a" oneconversion.bat "%~1" "%tempfile%a%%a" %%a
SHIFT
GOTO loop
)
)
timeout /t 1 >NUL
GOTO loop
```

**Code example of oneconversion.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL truepng.exe "%1"
CALL pngwolf.exe "%1"
DEL "%~2" >NUL 2>NUL
cls
exit
```

This works up to now.

---

But when I reserve first 10 parameters in use of commands.
**How I reserve commands**

```
FOR /f "TOKENS=1-11*" %%a in ("%*") DO (
SET filelist=%%l
)

SET varresize=%1
SHIFT
SET varincsmall=%1
SET varwidth=%2
SET varheight=%3
SET varjpegqa=%4
SET varjpegpr=%5
SET varjpegex=%6
SET varpngqa=%7
SET varpngcl=%8
SET varpngqt=%9
```

I don't know how can I use `%filelist%` inside main code. And sure replacing `%~1` with `%filelist%` doesn't work. Looks like I missed a point and couldn't find a way out.

Thanks for everyone will help or at least try to.

Comment: You already have it in `filelist` variable if I understand the question correctly, so just add `%filelist%` to parameters of oneconversion.bat. Otherwise maybe you can clarify what's wrong with it.

Comment: I edit question to clear up a bit more. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: So you want to invoke your main code like this: `main.bat resize incsmall width height ....... pngqt FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 FILE4` ?

Comment: I already do it. But I'm trying to make main code to call "oneconversion.bat" with just filelist "FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 FILE4" as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your variable initialization code at the start of the main script and shift the command line parameters additionally 9 times:

```
SET varresize=%1
SHIFT
SET varincsmall=%1
SET varwidth=%2
SET varheight=%3
SET varjpegqa=%4
SET varjpegpr=%5
SET varjpegex=%6
SET varpngqa=%7
SET varpngcl=%8
SET varpngqt=%9
for /L %%a in (1,1,9) do shift
```

Thus you won't need `filelist`, I think.

Comment: I think my mind has been blocked. Sure, since I started with SHIFT why not to keep going on it instead of modifying many parts of code (it's total 250+ lines).  Thank you to remind me the most straightforward way.